# Extract table names from TSQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, names

I have extracted some auto generated TSQL from a program and within the `FROM` section of the query there are a million (slightly exaggerated) `JOINS` to various tables.

Lots are repeats but with different aliases e.g. `table1`, `table1_1`, `table1_2` etc etc.
Is there a way or tool that will just list me the tables names at an aggregated level so I can see exactly which tables are being used?
e.g. in the above example I would just want to see `table1` listed.

Comment: What about query editor Ctrl+Shift+Q?

Comment: if you can extract the aliases, why can't you extract the table names? they will always be just before the aliases.

Comment: Wow @MitchWheat I guess your parents brought you up with no manners whatso ever. I thought this was a friendly forum but given your response to my question, you clearly go out of your way to insult otheres. As my username suggests, I am new to SQL so I appologise if my knowledge is not up there with your God like status.

Comment: Hi @KM. I know I can check them that way which is fine if it was say 10 or 20 lines of joins but there is 190 lines of joins and was just wondering if there was a way of easily viewing non-dup tables. If that makes sense. Going to give Dan's answer below, a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sp_describe_first_result_set with t@browse_information_mode = 1 to return query meta-data like the example below.  To get aggregated information, insert these results into a temp table or table variable and query to get the info you need.  The result table schema is described in the Books Online (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx).

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set 
    @tsql = N'
        SELECT t1.column_1, c.name
        FROM dbo.table_1 AS t1
        JOIN dbo.table_2 AS t2 ON
            t2.column_1 = t1.column_1'
    ,@params = NULL
    ,@browse_information_mode = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, I'll give that a go and see how I get on.